# Python - apply function in stead of iterrows does not work

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I just started using python.
The code below works, but it is not into coding standards as I think:

1. I get an error in the function `determine_direction`
2. everywhere I look, smart people say you should avoid errors and use apply function instead.

Can someone help me?

```
import pandas as pd

def determine_direction(df, fl_wr):
    # look up wind direction based on degrees
    # input: degrees - float
    # output: wind direction - string
    df_vlaremwindsel = df[(df['from'] <= fl_wr)]
    df_vlaremwindsel = df_vlaremwindsel[(fl_wr < df['to'])]
    str_direction = df_vlaremwindsel.index[0]
    return str_direction

# dataframe 1
lst_1 = {'NO': [22.5, 67.5], 'O': [67.5, 112.5], 'ZO': [112.5, 157.5], 'Z': [157.5, 202.5],
                   'ZW': [202.5, 257.5], 'W': [257.5, 292.5], 'NW': [292.5, 337.5], 'NNW': [337.5, 360.5],
                   'NNO': [0.5, 22.5], 'N': [0, 0.5]}
df_1= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=lst_1, orient='index', columns=['from', 'to'])

# dataframe 2 - testdata with degrees
lst_2 = [25.0, 88.1, 11, 356, 278, 169, 69, 1, 246]
df_2= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=lst_2)
# add empty column
df_2['direction']=''

#works, but i want to use .apply function
for i in range(len(df_2)):
    df_2.loc[i,['direction']] = determine_direction(df_1, df_2.iloc[i, 0])

print(df_2)
# apply function: does not work
# df_2['direction'].apply(determine_direction(df_1, df_2.loc['0']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of `df_2` running your code:

```
       0 direction
0   25.0        NO
1   88.1         O
2   11.0       NNO
3  356.0       NNW
4  278.0         W
5  169.0         Z
6   69.0         O
7    1.0       NNO
8  246.0        ZW
```

It's not so much about using `apply`. The task is to determine which interval your values fall into, and you can simplify by using `pd.cut` for this and providing the intervals:

```
df_1 = df_1.sort_values('from')
bins = np.unique(df_1.values)
labels = df_1.index
df_2= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=lst_2)
df_2['direction'] = pd.cut(df_2[0],bins = bins,labels = labels)

       0 direction
0   25.0        NO
1   88.1         O
2   11.0       NNO
3  356.0       NNW
4  278.0         W
5  169.0         Z
6   69.0         O
7    1.0       NNO
8  246.0        ZW
```

Comment: thx! this is much shorter and it looks simple, but i would never come up with that solution. It is also very fast on my dataset of ca. 1000000 records.